# Parsing JSON Array within JSON Object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have some JSON with the following structure:

```
{"source":[
           {"name":"john","age":20},
           {"name":"michael","age":25},
           {"name":"sara", "age":23}
         ]
}
```

I have named this JSON string as `mainJSON`. I'm trying to access the elements "name" and "age" with the following Java code:

```
JSONArray jsonMainArr = new JSONArray(mainJSON.getJSONArray("source"));
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) {  // **line 2**
     JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = childJSONObject.getString("name");
     int age     = childJSONObject.getInt("age");
}
```

I'm being shown the following exception for line number 2:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.
```

Please guide me as to where I'm making the mistake and how to rectify this.

Comment: There is no issue on your source code, I tried it already.

Answer (score 52):

`mainJSON.getJSONArray("source")` returns a `JSONArray`, hence you can remove the `new JSONArray.`

The JSONArray contructor with an object parameter expects it to be a Collection or Array (not JSONArray)

Try this:

```
JSONArray jsonMainArr = mainJSON.getJSONArray("source");
```

Comment: How can we parse JSON like this?

[{"id":"1","name":"ABC"},{"id":"2","name":"XYZ"}]

Comment: This may Help json = "{\"m\"="+json+"}"; and now parse by name 'm'.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is fine, just replace the following line:

```
JSONArray jsonMainArr = new JSONArray(mainJSON.getJSONArray("source"));
```

with this line:

```
JSONArray jsonMainArr = mainJSON.getJSONArray("source");
```

Comment: What if the data format received is [{dict1},{dict2},{dict3}]?

Comment: JSONArray list = new JSONArray(jsonString);

Answer (score 0):

line 2 should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.size(); i++) {  // **line 2**
```

For line 3, I'm having to do

```
    JSONObject childJSONObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonMainArr.get(i).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

 String jsonText = readAll(inputofyourjsonstream);
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
 JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("sources");
```

Your arr would looks like: [
    {
        "id":1001,
        "name":"jhon"
        },
        {
                "id":1002,
        "name":"jhon"
        }
]
You can use:

```
arr.getJSONObject(index)
```

to get the objects inside of the array.

Answer (score -3):

This could be an answer to your question:

```
JSONArray msg1 = (JSONArray) json.get("source");
for(int i = 0; i < msg1.length(); i++){
  String name = msg1.getString("name");
  int age     = msg1.getInt("age");
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: doesn't work - no reference back to "i" when iterating

Comment: Cannot cast the string to JSONArray, this doesn't work