# How to parse a JSONArray of JSONObjects in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I have the following array returned to my JAVA Android application from PHP:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [referral_fullname] => Name 1 [referral_balance] => 500 ) [1] => Array ( [referral_fullname] => Name 2 [referral_balance] => 500 ) );
```

In Java they above array looks like this:

```
{"0":{"referral_fullname":"Name 1","referral_balance":"500"},"1":{"referral_fullname":"Name 2","referral_balance":"500"}};
```

For a simple JSONObject I'm using:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(result.toString());
JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);

referral_fullname = finalResult.getString("referral_fullname");
```

but for an array of objects I don't know!

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object-using-java

Answer (score 4):

```
String str = your Json-> apply to.String();

    JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(str);


    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = jObject.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = jObject .getString(key);
        map.put(key,value);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Json Syntax is wrong , `JSONArray` should be like this :

```
["0":{"referral_fullname":"Name 1","referral_balance":"500"},"1":{"referral_fullname":"Name 2","referral_balance":"500"}];
```

and to parse a `JsonArray` that contains some `JSONObject` , try this :

```
//parse the result
            JSONObject jsonResult = null;
            JSONArray arrayResult = null;
            ArrayList<YourObject> listObjects = null;
            try {
                arrayResult = new JSONArray(result);
                if(arrayResult != null) {
                    listObjects = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
                    int lenght = arrayResult.length();
                    for(int i=0; i< lenght; i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = arrayResult.getJSONObject(i);
                        YourObject object = new YourObject(obj);
                        listObjects.add(object);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And add a constructor in your Class `YourObject` to convert your Json to an instance :

```
public YourObject(JSONObject json) {
    if (!json.isNull("referral_fullname"))
        this.referral_fullname = json.optString("referral_fullname", null);
    if (!json.isNull("referral_balance"))
        this.referral_balance = json.optString("referral_balance", null);
}
```

Comment: You were right, I checked once more and found that the returned value is not an array of objects but looks like an object of objects. How is that possible? I've tried even to parse it as an array an I get an error saying that a `JSONObject` cannot be converted into a `JSONArray`. Should I change something in my `PHP` code to have it returned as an array of objects or to parse it like it is now?

Comment: you should return an array of arrays in your php code , and try to convert it to json with : json_encode(yourArrayOFResult);

Comment: I'm confused about `new JSONArray(result)`. What version of json-lib supports this? I've seen this constructor signature (taking a string argument) documented, but when I try to use json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar, it says the only constructor for JSONArray takes no arguments (as shown here: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/index.html).

Comment: i'm talking about JSONArray of android json support, it is supported in Android without using any library Json

Comment: wtf ? `["0":{` is invalid

Comment: use json lint validator ( google it ) to check if the json is valid or not. 

And there is no need to say "wtf". -_-

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

if you can. You structure is now an object with two fields, 0 and 1, which contains another object. You have to get an array of object in place of this composite object if you want to iterate easily like

```
JSONObject jso;
for(int i = finalResult.lenght-1; i >=0; i--){
  jso = finalResult.get(i);
  // jso == {"referral_fullname":"Name 1","referral_balance":"500"}

  [whatever]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.............

```
final JSONArray result_array = json.getJSONArray("result"); 

for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

JSONObject joObject = result_array.getJSONObject(i);
String jName = joObject.get("referral_fullname").toString();
String jbalance = joObject.get("referral_balance").toString();

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First make an JSON object and see then in inner level what you have if you have array then fetch array.
You need to make JSON object first. For example, if resp is a String (for example coming as http response)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
```

jsonObject may contains other JSON Objects or JSON array. How to convert the JSON depends on the response.
If arraykey is a array inside the JSON objects then we can get list of array by the following way.

```
JSONArray arr  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arraykey");
```

Check the length of arr, if it is greater than 0 then it contains JSON objects or JSON array depending the data.
There is a complete example with some explanation about JSON String to JSON array can be found at 
http://www.hemelix.com/JSONHandling