# Removing the end [ and ] from php Json result for Android Java code

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

My PHP code is this:

```
$userdetails = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM aircraft_status"); 

#$row = mysql_fetch_row($userdetails) ;

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($userdetails)){
$status[]= array($rows['Aircraft']=>$rows['Status']);
}
#Output the JSON data
echo json_encode($status);
```

and gives this:

```
[{"A70_870":"1"},{"A70_871":"1"},{"A70_872":"1"},{"A70_873":"1"},{"A70_874":"1"},{"A70_875":"1"},{"A70_876":"2"},{"A70_877":"1"},{"A70_878":"2"},{"A70_879":"2"},{"A70_880":"2"},{"A70_881":"0"},{"A70_882":"0"},{"A70_883":"0"},{"A70_884":"0"},{"A70_885":"0"}]
```

The java code that reads it is this:

```
// Create a JSON object from the request response
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    //Retrieve the data from the JSON object
        n870 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_870");
        n871 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_871");
        n872 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_872");
        n873 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_873");
        n874 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_874");
        n875 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_875");
        n876 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_876");
        n877 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_877");
        n878 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_878");
        n879 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_879");
        n880 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_880");
        n881 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_881");
        n882 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_882");
        n883 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_883");
        n884 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_884");
        n885 = jsonObject.getInt("A70_885");
```

When i run my android app I seem to keep getting the error:

```
"of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted into Json object"
```

However when I send the app dummy code without the square brackets, it seems to work fine! How do I get rid of those [ and ] brackets on the ends???

Alternatively is there a way to accept the json as it is and adapt the java to read it?

Comment: removing the brackets will break the json. You've got an array of objects. taking off the brackets "deletes" the array, and now you've got a bunch of comma-separated objects, which is NOT valid javascript/json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with this kind of json structure?

```
$status[$rows['Aircraft']]= $rows['Status'];
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone else who answered also, but this worked perfectly first go!!!! Cheers Lajos! you are the man.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode($status, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lrYKv6

or

```
echo json_encode((Object) $status);
```

Demo; http://codepad.viper-7.com/RPtchU

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JSonobject, use JSONArray

```
   JSONArray array = new JSONArray(sourceString);
```

Later loop through the array and do the business logic.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 0):

You get an JSONArray, Not Object, you could create an Object holding an array, or parsing the array.
Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object) post

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1 (Java)

How about a helper method like this:

```
private int getProp(String name, JSONArray arr) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        if (obj.has(name))
            return obj.getInt(name);
    }
    throw new Exception("Key not found");
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result); // note the *JSONArray* vs your *JSONObject*
n870 = getProp("A70_870", jsonArray);
n871 = getProp("A70_871", jsonArray);
...
```

Note I haven't tested this code, so you may need to make some changes...

### Alternate solution (PHP)

It's been awhile since I've worked with PHP, but you might be able to leave your Java code intact and change your PHP int the `while`-loop body to:

```
$status[$rows['Aircraft']] = $rows['Status'];
```