# Problems parsing JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

I have this json:

```
[{
    "name": "prog 1",
    "show": [{
        "name": "n1",
        "time": "01.10 "
    }, {
        "name": "n2",
        "time": "01.35 "
    }]
}, {
    "name": "prog 2",
    "show": [{
        "name": "n1",
        "time": "01.10 "
    }, {
        "name": "n2",
        "time": "01.35 "
    }]
}]
```

Now trying to parse it in Java like:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(json_str);
```

throws an Exception, since it doesn't begin with {, but [ since it's an array. I can parse this without problem in js, but aparently I cannot load an JSONArray with this string...

Comment: check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object if it can help.

Comment: Sometimes it gets easier for us to help you if you not only describe the exception you got, but also include the stacktrace in your question.

Comment: The input contains an array, not an object.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the syntax.  You have an array of objects (and the objects contain arrays).  You need to use JSONArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: `JSONArray  objArray = new JSONArray (json_str);`

```
// to access the individual objects inside the array:

for(int i=0;i<objArray.length();i++)
{
  JSONObject obj = objArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(stringWithContent);
```

Then access it like :

```
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length();i++){
        System.out.println(arr.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(json_str);
JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("show");    
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"));
}
```

It will helpful ...