# How to parse a JSON array inside JSON Object in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am developing a android application which fetches some data from the server. I use JSON for that. I have to parse a JSON response which has a structure like below:

```
{
  "dataset1":["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  "dataset2":["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  "dataset3":["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  "dataset4":["1", "2", "3", "4"]
}
```

I tried searching the internet but couldn't get an idea how to parse a response like this. Can anyone please show me a way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/google-gson/google-gson

Comment: [try this](http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_layxkurNJE1qzpwi0o1_500.jpg)

Comment: "tried searching the internet". have you tried searching on stackoverflow.com? There are tons of JSON related questions here. Including a lot of duplicates that also answer your question

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonDataset1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dataset1");
JSONArray jsonDataset2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dataset2");
JSONArray jsonDataset3 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dataset3");
JSONArray jsonDataset4 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dataset4");
```

Comment: Still i feel it is the responsibility of the asker to decide ,he will know where this may lead him in the future.