# How to get all rows from phpmyadmin database in Android?

Tags: java, android, phpmyadmin

How do I to get all rows from a phpmyadmin database and display them in Android?

When I get one rows all is good. When I try to read all rows, I get only the last row.

My php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id831385_rootroot", "rootroot", "id831385_bukrisk");

$accept= $_POST["accept"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE accept= ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $accept);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,  $id_pay, $id_user, $value, $accept);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["id_pay"] = $id_pay;
    $response["id_user"] = $id_user;
    $response["value"] = $value;
    $response["accept"] = $accept;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

My java request :

```
public class GetPaymentsRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "https://pacinho.000webhostapp.com/PaymentsList.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public GetPaymentsRequest(String accept, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("accept", accept);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

My java code in activity:

```
     Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if (success) {
                        int id_pay = jsonResponse.getInt("id_pay");
                        int id_user = jsonResponse.getInt("id_user");
                        int value = jsonResponse.getInt("value");

                        //Toast.makeText(myView.getContext(),""+id_pay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        String id_payS = String.valueOf(id_pay);
                        String id_userS = String.valueOf(id_user);
                        String valueS = String.valueOf(value);

                        showPay.setText(showPay.getText() + " " + id_payS);
                        //UserPayments UP = new UserPayments(id_payS,id_userS,valueS);
                        //paymentsList.add(UP);

                        //paymentsCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

GetPaymentsRequest paymentsRequest = new GetPaymentsRequest("0", responseListener);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(myView.getContext());
queue.add(paymentsRequest);
```

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not a database. It is an administration tool. The real database you are using is (probably) MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line you fetch your PHP code is just overwriting the values of `$response`. You should instead create an array and put all the rows in it

```
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $payment = array();
    $payment["success"] = true;
    $payment["id_pay"] = $id_pay;
    $payment["id_user"] = $id_user;
    $payment["value"] = $value;
    $payment["accept"] = $accept;
    $response[] = $payment;
}
```

You will also need to modify the code in the android side to handle the array.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't know what do that. How to do this in Android . Thanks !

Comment: @AllPacinho this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36460922/3072566) might help you