# How to print a json object

Tags: arrays, json

Hi Im new to JSON this may be a basic question, im having data as a JSON object and i want to print the "message" data alone. My sample JSON data, in this how can i access message?

```
{
"name": "Usingtagproject",
"fan_count": 0,
"category": "Product/Service",
"feed": {
"data": [
  {
    "created_time": "2017-05-02T18:24:27+0000",
    "message": "hii",
  },
  {
    "created_time": "2017-05-02T09:26:37+0000",
    "message": "Hi Google",
  },
  {
    "created_time": "2017-05-02T09:24:26+0000",
    "message": "Hi Demoproject",
  }
],
}
```

Comment: That completely depends on which language you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON Array within JSON Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object)

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object

Answer (score 1):

JSON is essentially a map (keys with values), that has a specific syntax.
It completely depends on what language you're accessing it in, but you can assume that most languages will have key indexing, so that you can say:

```
string name = my_json['name']
list<map> data = my_json['data']

for data_map in data:
  print "found message: " + data_map['message']
```