# JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array while parsing a JSON Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON with the below structure:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "2019-07-12 00:29:37",
        "OutletTemperatureCV": "31.5",
        "ChocolateMixingTemperatureCV": "30.399999",
        "WaterCoolingTemperatureCV": "13.899",
        "WaterMixingTemperatureCV": "31.5"
    }
]
```

The Json file is named as temperer. I am trying to parse this json array to get values values.

```
JSONArray array1=new JSONArray(temperer);
for (int n = 0; n < array1.length(); n++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = array1.getJSONObject(n); 
    String time= jsonObject.getString("timestamp");
    String outletTemp= jsonObject.getString("OutletTemperatureCV");
    String outletTemp= jsonObject.getString("ChocolateMixingTemperatureCV");
    String outletTemp= jsonObject.getString("WaterCoolingTemperatureCV");
    String outletTemp= jsonObject.getString("WaterMixingTemperatureCV");
}
```

But when I try this code, I get the below error..

> org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or
>   collection or array.

I saw another post in SO with a similar prob, but this example uses a named JSON array. 
([Parsing JSON Array within JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650171/parsing-json-array-within-json-object))

How can I get over this error for an unnamed JSON array?
Any solutions will be hugely helpful :(

Comment: What is the datatype of variable `temperer`? It should be of String type containing the json string.

Comment: are you reading from file?  is temperature a file or variable? if variable, please share details of it

Comment: Hi, the temperer json is dynamically obtained from an API call. Structure will be the same as given here, which is an unnamed Json array if I am not wrong?

Comment: can you add some more code, including temper type @Krishna

Comment: Turns out my temperer is a String with a named array. I am not sure how to iterate over the named array now. Will post it as a separate question to avoid more confusion. Thanks for trying to help me out